# Store SQL script in a postgres stored procedure

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, ddl

I have about 140 line of mostly DDL SQL commands.

For example:

```
drop table xxxx
select into xxxx from yyyy
alter table xxxx add ....
update xxxxx ....
```

Is possible to store this kind of script in a postgres stored procedure?

Comment: Of course you can, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I got a bunch of weird errors.


CREATE FUNCTION test() 
RETURNS void AS $$

drop table xxxx;
select into xxxx from yyyy;
alter table xxxx add ....;
update xxxxx ....;

$$ LANGUAGE sql;

Comment: Please show us the problematic errors and the relevant code

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the **complete** source code of your function ([edit] your question do not post code in comments)